Vulkan implicit syncrhonization guarantees
In the Vulkan spec (referencing that of v1.0 and v1.3):

Submission order is a fundamental ordering in Vulkan, giving meaning to the order in which action and synchronization commands are recorded and submitted to a single queue.

Italics're mine, it linked to relevant section in the spec, which list 4 categorization of commands: actions, state-setting, synchronization, and indirect.
My question is simple. Does this submission order mean that if 2 commands A happens before B, and both are either action or sync commands, then B won't start before A completes?

Apparently no: https://www.khronos.org/assets/uploads/developers/presentations/Ensure_Vulkan_Synchronization_Vulkanised_Oct_2021.pdf

If one or both A and B is sync op, then they may be serialized - I said "may" because not all forms of sync op wait on both sides.
If both are action ops, then they're out-of-order - they're only in-order with respect to the sync ops that happen before or after them. That's why action ops are mentioned alongside sync ops.
